# Identify column separation in PDF text extraction - itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I using itextsharp to extract the text from a PDF file.

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, pageNumber, strategy);

currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
return currentText;
```

With that code I could obtain all information in plain text, that’s great.  But, when I try to process it, I found that I can’t know where a specific column start and when ends.

This is the example table example:

[image: The fields could be multiline]

After extracting the text I obtain something like this

```
Name
Details
Note
MYNAME
THIS ARE THE 
DETAILS
HERE YOU CAN
FIND A NOTE
```

As you can see, It is hard to know where a column information start and where ends...

¿Any idea to identify the column separation?

Thanks a lot

**Environment**

PDF Tagged: No

itextsharp  5.4.3.0

.Net        4

Comment: Is your PDF tagged? If so, iText can extract the table as XML. If not, the table you see with human eyes can't be seen by a machine, unless Artificial Intelligence is involved.

Comment: How do I know if the PDF is tagged?

Comment: Open the PDF in Adobe Reader and look at File > Document Properties > Description. At the bottom of the dialog window, you'll see a label "Tagged PDF" followed by either Yes or No.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie. I just review it, but it's not tagged.